# How can we open a URL in Chrome Icognito mode using Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, browser, robotframework

Can anyone please help me how to open a URL in Chrome browser in **Icognito mode**, as the URL that i'm trying to open in chrome is giving 404 error but is opening successfully in Icognito.
Please guide me what Robot command should be given to open in **Icognito mode**.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ${options}=    Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    incognito
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect answer, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Open Browser  |  ${url}  |  Chrome  |  options=add_argument("--incognito")

Answer (score -1):

Robotframework always creates a 'clean' session of chrome so it shouldn't make a difference.

If you still want to run a incognito session, you could set --incognito option:

```
Open Browser      ${url}      Chrome     options=addArguments("--incognito")
```

You can find what you can pass to the browser here: http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser

Comment: reading SeleniumLibrary documentation, my proposal should work.

Comment: Read it as well, *should* work. Did you test in on your machine?

Comment: Didn't work for me, it opened the browser in normal mode itself

Comment: I have Chrome v.78, ChromeDriver v.78 and SeleniumLibrary 3.3.1. After upgrading SeleniumLibrary to 4.1, browser does not open at all, instead, getting `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'addArguments'` error.